# Prevent auto update of control inside a designer file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control `MyControls.MyControl` which I retrieve from a virtual path. `Root1\MyWebsite\MyPage` is used is the website app pool in IIS. Then `Root2\MyControls\MyControl` is a child app pool under the website app pool in IIS.

Every time I change the HTML of the page, the designer file gets auto updated. However, since Visual Studios cannot find the physical path of `MyControls.MyControl` at save time, it auto updates it to `protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl myControl;`. Is there some way to prevent this? Maybe an annotation I can add to prevent auto-update once a control has been auto-generated in the designer file?

MyPage.aspx.designer.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// myControl control.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// </remarks>
protected global::MyControls.MyControl myControl;
```

MyPage.aspx:

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" culture="auto" enableEventValidation="false"
    Inherits="MyWebsite.MyPage" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MyMasterPage.Master" 
    RequiresJQueryUI="true" uiculture="auto"  %>

<%@ Register Src="~/MyControls/MyControl.ascx" TagName="MyControl" TagPrefix="mc" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phBody" runat="server">
    <mc:MyControl runat="server" id="myControl"></mc:MyControl>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Why do you care if VS changes your designer file? By definition, that's what the designer file is there for. You shouldn't be messing with the designer file, just the regular code behind.

Comment: @mason Every time it updates the designer file, it updates it to the incorrect control. This will fail the build, and it requires make to fix the path every time I do an HTML change.

Comment: You have properly registered the control on your page? I think you need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example isn't complete.

Comment: What causes you to say "Visual Studios cannot find the physical path of MyControls.MyControl"? Is the file at the correct location as shown in your `src` attribute? Is it included in the project?

Comment: It's a virtual path, so it won't be in that exact relative path physically. It'll only find it during run time. Yes, the project is included in the project (hence it building when it's in the designer file).

Comment: What do you mean it won't be in the exact relative path physically? `MyControl.ascx` should be in a folder called `MyControls` that is at the root of your project.

Comment: Why isn't the control in the same project that it's to be used from?

Comment: @mason It's in a shared app pool. This is useful because you can use the same control across many different websites and app pools.

Comment: Perhaps you should add the .ascx to each project that needs it as a linked item. That way you only have one copy and they're all pointing to the same one. Or put the .ascx in a Git submodule. Or [turn it into a custom control](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidebb/2005/10/31/turning-an-ascx-user-control-into-a-redistributable-custom-control/) that you can consume from each project via NuGet.

Comment: @mason Having multiple copies of the .ascx is one of the things I'm trying to avoid. I want only one copy of the code to avoid the duplicate code issue.

Comment: I just suggested three different methods to avoid having multiple copies.